# How to connect to S3 with access key credentails on spark (AWS Glue)

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to connect to S3 bucket with credentials (access_key id/password) on AWS Glue

the following script does not work

```py
sc = SparkContext() 

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "...") 

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key","...") 

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider") 

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
```

Comment: Why you do not use IAM access? This is an anti-pattern to use keys in your code

Comment: Can you post the trace of the error that you receive?

Comment: Why not use boto3 lib to access S3?